# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

Hopefully I can get some help... Been searching for an answer on this for 24hrs now... I cannot seem to find why it is occurring. It only happens on one page (POST METHOD)... every other page is fine.

I am not an expert with Laravel, but i thoght i had it all sorted as it is working fine on my local server. Once deployed, all is good but that one page that does not insert into the DB and returns a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Using Laravel Framework 5.6.12

Route:

```
Route::get('/requests/new', 'RequestsController@newRequest')->name('new_request');    
Route::post('/requests/new', 'RequestsController@newRequest')->name('new_request');
```

Controller:

```
 public function newRequest(Request $request){

            $service = new Service();

            $title = $request->input('title');
            $name = $request->input('name');
            $last_name = $request->input('last_name');
            $address = $request->input('address');
            $postcode = $request->input('postcode');
            $city = $request->input('city');
            $county = $request->input('county');
            $email = $request->input('email');
            $date = $request->input('date');
            $service_id = $request->input('service_id');

            if( $request->isMethod('post') )
                {
                    // dd($data);
                    $this->validate(
                        $request,
                        [
                            'name' => 'required|min:3',
                            'last_name' => 'required',
                            'address' => 'required',
                            'postcode' => 'required',
                            'city' => 'required',
                            'county' => 'required',
                            'email' => 'required',

                        ]
                    );

                }

            $data = array("title"=>$title,"name"=>$name,"last_name"=>$last_name,"address"=>$address,"postcode"=>$postcode,"city"=>$city,"county"=>$county,"email"=>$email,"date"=>$date,"service_id"=>$service_id);

            DB::table('requests')->insert(($data));

            $data_r['requests']= $service->getRequests(); 

            return view('requests/new', $data_r);
       }
```

Service Model:

```
public function getRequests()
    {

        $latest_request = DB::table('requests as r')
                                        ->select('r.request_id')
                                        ->orderBy('r.request_id', 'desc')
                                        ->get()
        ;

        return $latest_request;
    }
```

And my view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="cont_client">
<div class="row">
      <div class="medium-12 large-12 columns " >
        <h4>STEP 2: Enter booking information</h4>
        <div class="form_cont">
        <form action="/requests/new" method="post">
         {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input name="service_id" type="hidden" value="{{ $service_id }}" readonly >
          <div class="medium-4  columns">
            <label>Title</label>
            <select name="title">
                         @foreach ($titles as $title )
                              <option value="{{ $title }}" >{{ $title }}.</option>
                        @endforeach 
                        </select>
          </div>
          <div class="medium-4  columns">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input name="name" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="medium-4  columns">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input name="last_name" type="text">
          </div>

           <div class="medium-4  columns">
            <label>Date</label>
            <input name="date" type="date" value="{{ $date }}" readonly>
          </div>
          <div class="medium-8  columns">
            <label>Address</label>
            <input name="address" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="medium-4  columns">
            <label>Post Code</label>
            <input name="postcode" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="medium-4  columns">
            <label>City</label>
            <input name="city" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="medium-4  columns">
            <label>County</label>
            <input name="county" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="medium-12  columns">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input name="email" type="text" value="{{{ isset(Auth::user()->email) ? Auth::user()->email : Auth::user()->email }}}" readonly>
          </div>
          <div class="medium-12  columns">
            <input value="CONFIRM" class="button success btn_right" type="submit" >
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

It is without saying that  it works fine on a local server (XAMPP).

- I tried several browsers as I found out the issue could be related to
  that, but even clearing all cache, data, cookies, no change and still not working.
- I have another page that does something very similar (insert into database and validate - returns view and data) and it is working fine.
- Using shared hosting. But everything else, including the 'similar' page works fine. Only this one is looking like an issue.

Cookies for whoever can help me here!

Comment: Not sure if it helps but trying the different pages...And when I get the error, I end up in a URL at the root of the folder...


All my files are in www.mysite.com/project


and when I navigate through my pages I always end up with URLS like...


www.mysite.com/project/modify


www.mysite.com/project/bookings


but when I do get the error, I end up on the root...


www.mysite.com/requests


not sure if this could be of some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to split the GET and POST request into 2 different functions.

```
    Route::get('/requests/new', 'RequestsController@newRequest')->name('request.new');    
Route::post('/requests/new', 'RequestsController@newRequestPost')->name('request.post');
```

To simplify the code you could simply use `$service = new Service($request->all());` as long as your Service model fields are fillable. Run `$service->save();` and done. The `id` is added automatically.

Finally you need to redirect the POST request to a GET request `return redirect()->route('request.show', [$service->id])->with(['success' => 'Your request has been added']);`

Create the route `Route::get('/request/{id}', 'RequestsController@requestShow')->name('request.show');` and handle the view from there.

It is not laravel that loops. It's your browser.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Having 2 different route names for the route was what fixed it with changing the post action on the form  to the name of the actual route instead of the path.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the get and the post in diferent functions...
its look like the browser entered in loop cause de routes.

Comment: Just tried. Not working.

I also tried removing the GET route altogether and replace the 'return view' with a echo for testing. The same issue occurs.

I renamed the view file to something different so none of the name match... working on local, but no on the hosting.

Pulling my hair out right now!

Comment: this is very odd... the only thing that i can try is, put a dd('something') on first line and after every teste go with dd down.this way you will see the correct line who was the bug

Comment: try to use only one parantheses on DB::table('requests')->insert(($data));

this may be throwing you into an error screen that redirects and gives you the loop

Comment: Thanks for your help! Finally sorted it. Changed the post action on the form to a specified route name for the post. :)